# In c# how to use String.Format for a number and pad left with zeros so its always 6 chars

Tags: c#

I want to use c# format to do this:

6 = "000006"
999999 = "999999"
100 = "000100"
-72 = error
1000000 = error

I was trying to use String.Format but without success.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Formatting will not produce an error if there are too many digits. You can achieve a left-padded 6 digit string just with

```
string output = number.ToString("000000");
```

If you need 7 digit strings to be invalid, you'll just need to code that.

```
if (number >= 0 and number < 1000000)
{
     output = number.ToString("000000")
}
else 
{
     throw new ArgumentException("number");
}
```

---

To use string.Format, you would write

```
string output = string.Format("{0:000000}", number);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use String.Format?

Comment: string.Format() just calls ToString() on the int, so there is less overhead if you use ToString() directly.

Comment: @phoog: Unless you're already using String.Format.  I strongly prefer String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}-{1:0000}-{2}", DateTime.Now, number, foo) over String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), number.ToString("0000"), foo)

Comment: @Timbo absolutely.  Why would anyone do the latter?

Comment: @phoog: Someone might do the latter if they were carelessly/naively following your advice that number formatting via ToString has less overhead than via string.Format.  I was just pointing out that this is only true when dealing with a single object.

Comment: @Timbo that's a good point.  I have a colleague who writes data into temporary tables to avoid using, for example, `WHERE PostalCode IN (...`.  The query is a one-off; the chance of using the same list again is very small, so I am fairly certain that the overhead of creating the table outweighs whatever performance benefit one might gain in running the query itself.  (I haven't actually measured, so grain of salt.)  It is definitely important to remember that "x is faster" almost always implies certain circumstances which will not apply in every context.